# How to create a textView below a circle(used canvas to draw) in android

Tags: java, android, canvas, textview

I wanted draw a circle on a activity which has the largest radius in portrait view. So I used canvas for that purpose. However I could draw the circle. Now I want to create a text view below this circle .

There is code for drawing the circle.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SimpleGestureFilter.SimpleGestureListener {

    Context context=this;
    private SimpleGestureFilter detector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new CircleCanvas(this));
        detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
        // Call onTouchEvent of SimpleGestureFilter class
        this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSwipe(int direction) {
        String str = "";

        switch (direction) {

            case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT :
                str="Swipe Right";
                break;
            case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT :  Intent intent_3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent_3);
                str = "Swipe Left";
                break;
            case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN :  str = "Swipe Down";
                break;
            case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP :    str = "Swipe Up";
                break;

        }
        Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDoubleTap() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Double Tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

And this is my view class,

**CircleCanvas.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by user on 4/26/2016.
 */
public class CircleCanvas extends View {

    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    Context context1;

    public CircleCanvas(Context context) {
        super(context);
        context1=context;
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

        ((Activity)context1).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

        int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        Log.d("Width"," -- "+width);
        Log.d("Height"," -- "+height);

        float h=height/2;
        float w=width/2;
        float r=width/2;

        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        canvas.drawCircle(w, h,r, paint);


    }
}
```

How could I draw a circle below this circle ?
Do you have any idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, you should maybe override onMeasure for CircleCanvas View and set needed dimensions. Then you could just add TextView, or use canvas drawText

Comment: @PetrovDmitrii : Can you provide me a code example ?

Comment: Hey you want to put a textView under your circle or draw another circle ?
"How could I draw a circle below this circle ? Do you have any idea ?"
" Now I want to create a text view below this circle "

Because if you want to put a textview below your circle I can provide you a code exemple

Comment: Yes I want to put a text below my circle